# Question about expression "Referring to"

Tags: word-usage, expressions

I have a question about the usage of "referring to". Let's assume that you are in a meeting and you are giving a presentation. You have to explain about a couple of things  that are in the table chart one by one. 
In this situation, I 'd like to use "referring to " to let my audience know about which one I'm talking about. For example, I want to start by saying "referring to number 7 item which talks about~~ ,  we finished our work for that by ~~~. 
Is this correct or wrong?
Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

"Referring to" works fine, but you may want to use some variants if you want to talk about many elements in the chart. "In reference to item 7...", "As far as #7 goes...", "With regard to #7...", etc.

Comment: You just beat me to the submit button!

Comment: As you can see clearly in chart number 5 /  Let's go to the next visualisation. / Chart number 3 shows the funktion exacly.

Comment: A good expert answer includes explanation, context, and supporting facts. This is what makes the answer useful – not only to the asker, but to future visitors to the page. Please consider expanding your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think "referring to" works in this case, it sounds natural and normal.

You might want use some other substitutes as well, such as

- "regarding"
- "concerning"
- "about"

The following might work, depending on how you use them

- "with respect to"
- "touching on"
- "on" (like "on item number x")